# Inject custom tag(s) into HEAD/page for tests only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

What would be the best way to inject custom script tag into head/page for tests only?

I'm writing feature specs with capybara, and I need to mock some 3-rd party api calls in the browser, I need to inject javascript code.

I tried to `page.execute_script`, but it was too late. 3-rd party api calls are executed immediately on DOM ready. So I need to mock things before DOM ready.

I have some ideas, but I wonder what would be the best way?

Similar questions without answers:

- [Using Capybara-Webkit, Inject Javascript before client code runs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34935587/using-capybara-webkit-inject-javascript-before-client-code-runs)
- [How can I include javascript with javascript_include_tag at the top of the page for a capybara test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36683421/how-can-i-include-javascript-with-javascript-include-tag-at-the-top-of-the-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really the only way to do exactly what you're asking would be conditional code in your html templates, based on being in the test_environment (Rails.env.test?).  However a much better solution is to use a programmable proxy like [puffing_billy](https://github.com/oesmith/puffing-billy) to mock the responses the 3-rd party api would actually send.  That way you are still testing the code that would actually be used in production.

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me! I'm using puffing billy, it surprisingly works very well